# Get shell script "read" value from python script

Tags: python, bash, shell

Shell script:
Hello.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Enter your name: "
read name
echo "Hello $name"
```

I want to invoke Hello.sh from within python and fill variable "name" non-interactively.
How can it be done?

Comment: what do you mean by "from a python script" ???

Comment: do you want to give the value from variable "name" _to_ a python script or _get_ the variable name _from_ a python script?

Comment: To clarify: he likely wants to invoke `Hello.sh` from within `python` and "fill" `name` noninteractively.  If so, I believe that the answer John's looking for is to use `subprocess` and `write` to the `stdin` handle.

Comment: Exactly what Brian Cain is saying is what I m looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how to read your question.

EDIT:  Comment was added by the OP:
*invoke Hello.sh from within python and "fill" name noninteractively*

Which changes things, so here is a different answer for the new question:

```
import subprocess
cmd = '/home/user1/Hello.sh'
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
proc.communicate("Fred Bloggs")
```

I have used the full path to the script, it is safer.

Comment: invoke Hello.sh from within python and "fill" name noninteractively

Answer (score 0):

```
name = raw_input('Enter your name: ')
print 'Hello ', name
```

Comment: invoke Hello.sh from within python and "fill" name noninteractively