# Enter shell script variable value non-interactively using python

Tags: python, bash, shell, subprocess, stdin

Shell script:
Hello.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Enter your name: "
read name
echo "Hello $name"
```

I want to invoke Hello.sh from within python and fill variable "name" non-interactively. How can it be done?

Comment: This is the same as your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15548393/get-shell-script-read-value-from-python-script).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

+1 on the [pipes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15551493/1974792). A more "shell-ish" approach would be:

```
import subprocess

the_name = 'the_name'
myproc = subprocess.Popen(['echo %s | bash Hello.sh' % the_name], stdin = subprocess.PIPE, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
out, err = myproc.communicate()

print out
```

Comment: with `shell=True`, I believe that it is preferred to pass a string, not a list.

Comment: @mgilson when `shell=True`: _If args is a string, the string specifies the command to execute through the shell. If args is a sequence, the first item specifies the command string, and any additional items will be treated as additional arguments to the shell itself._ So it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Thanks it worked the way I wanted it to.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to `Popen.communicate` with the subprocess:

```
from subprocess import Popen,PIPE
p = Popen(['bash','./Hello.sh'],stdin=PIPE,stderr=PIPE,stdout=PIPE)
stdout_data,stderr_data = p.communicate("Hello World!\n")
```